# A subalgebra of a Frobenius algebra that is not again a Frobenius algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, topological-quantum-field-theory

A **Frobenius algebra** is a vector space that is both an algebra and a coalgebra in a compatible way. (See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+algebra#AsAssociativeAlgebraWithLinearForm) for a precise definition.) I guess that a subalgebra of a Frobenius algebra is not again a Frobenius algebra? What is an instructive example that demonstrates this?

Comment: Matrix algebras over a field are Frobenius and every finite dimensional algebra embeds in a matrix algebra but many of them are not Frobenius

Comment: The ring $K[x]/x^{n+1}$ is a Frobenius algebra, with the coproduct sending $x^i$ to $\sum_{j+k=n+i}x^j\otimes x^k$, but the subalgebra generated by $\{x^i:i>1\}$ is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any finite dimensional $k$-algebra $A$ is also a subalgebra of its trivial extension $$T(A)=A \oplus \rm{Hom}_k(A,k),$$ which is Frobenius. In this way you get examples where the Frobenius algebra is not semi-simple.

The (symmetric) $k$-bilinear form on $T(A)$ is given by $$\langle (a,f),(b,g) \rangle = g(a)+f(b),$$ for $(a,f),(b,g) \in T(A)$, see section 3 in:

*Bessenrodt, Christine; Holm, Thorsten; Zimmermann, Alexander*, [**Generalized Reynolds ideals for non-symmetric algebras.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2007.02.028), J. Algebra 312, No. 2, 985-994 (2007). [ZBL1119.16001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1119.16001).

Comment: Wow, that's a handy way to produce a Frobenius algebra I haven't run across.  What's the associated form?  I was guessing something like $(a,f)(b,g)=f(b)g(a)$... maybe the $A$ module action has to be like this: $(a\cdot f)(x)=f(ax)$?

Comment: @rschwieb, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229412/trivial-extension-of-an-algebra proves it symmetric although it doesn’t spell out the form.  It shows it is isomorphic to its dual as a bimodule.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Looks like my conjecture about the form was incorrect, although it looks like there's echoes of that in the post linked...  I guess sometime I'll have to unravel it.

Comment: @rschweib The symmetric bilinear form is $f(b)+g(a)$. I will add a reference.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen ooh, I was close. Please use autocomplete to get my name's vowels in the right order :) I hate to miss updates...

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry about that. It's too late to change it now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

To make Benjamin Steinberg's (very apt) observation concrete, one may take $T_2(F)$, the upper triangular matrix ring over a field.

It is not Frobenius because it is not self-injective, but it's certainly a subring of a Frobenius algebra, namely $M_2(F)$.

Comment: One can find many finite dimensional algebras that aren't Frobenius in [this DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=63l&L=18); however, there's no way to filter down to which ones are actually f.d. algebras over fields explicitly.